# how do i prevent my moving div from going out of the page/screen in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is what i tried but it keeps moving outside of the page/screen.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key === 37) {
      $('#divResult').animate({
        left: "-=50"
      })
    }
    if (key === 38) {
      $('#divResult').animate({
        top: "-=50"
      })
    }
    if (key === 39) {
      $('#divResult').animate({
        left: "+=50"
      })
    }
    if (key === 40) {
      $('#divResult').animate({
        top: "+=50"
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

How do i prevent the moving div from going outside of the page/screen in jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check window boundaries by using  `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` against div position, also I would advise you to use `event.Key` because native `event.which`(not the jQuery one) is deprecated

```js
let animationInProgress = false;
const debounceTime = 100; // milliseconds to debounce

$(document).on('keydown', (e) => {
  if (animationInProgress) return;
  animationInProgress = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    animationInProgress = false;
  }, debounceTime);

  const key = e.key;
  const $divResult = $('#divResult');
  const currentPosition = $divResult.position();
  const pageWidth = $(window).width();
  const pageHeight = $(window).height();
  const divWidth = $divResult.width();
  const divHeight = $divResult.height();
  const step = 50 // whatever value you want here - you had 50 in your example;

  let newLeft, newTop;

  if (key === "ArrowLeft" && currentPosition.left > 0) {
    newLeft = Math.max(currentPosition.left - step, 0);
    $divResult.animate({
      left: newLeft
    });
  }
  if (key === "ArrowUp" && currentPosition.top > 0) {
    newTop = Math.max(currentPosition.top - step, 0);
    $divResult.animate({
      top: newTop
    });
  }
  if (key === "ArrowRight" && currentPosition.left + divWidth < pageWidth) {
    newLeft = Math.min(currentPosition.left + step, pageWidth - divWidth);
    $divResult.animate({
      left: newLeft
    });
  }
  if (key === "ArrowDown" && currentPosition.top + divHeight < pageHeight) {
    newTop = Math.min(currentPosition.top + step, pageHeight - divHeight);
    $divResult.animate({
      top: newTop
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#divResult {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's not working well, the box jumps to all right if right arrow is pressed. Also the box still dissapears out of the screen if its not on the top left corner. And after a couple of times moving i can't move it anymore.

Comment: none of what you said happen in my snippet. I even edited it to start it centered(ish) and not top/left

Comment: is there a way to use my first snippet above and write less code to accomplish the same thing? your code is good, dont get me wrong but it's so much code and my written code has dissapeared totally.